# Reveal in Finder for Photos.app?

Tags: finder, macos, photos.app

I've recently taken the dive to Photos.app on Sierra and it does seem to finally replace iPhoto, but I am stuck in a rut with not being able to get to the original photos and videos via a right click and reveal in Finder function.  Is there a plugin or some option that facilitates this?

At the moment I'm having to drop to shell and issue an `lsof` to get file paths, but that's quite cumbersome...

Comment: Are you trying to see the photos filepaths? Or are you looking for a way to open them directly in Finder?

Comment: Both...........

Comment: Not sure there's a way to do this but I won't affirm anything. Just for you to know, the photo files are located in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/originals/` (since Catalina I think).

Comment: Yep, I know this - the problem is that users frequently need more clean access to images for many and sundry reasons. Apple has not given two craps about my feedback on this since 2016, but hey, that's apple. They're just a crap company now and have been for the past ten or so years and have no signs of improving their previously awesome dev and user experience. Lesser of the poisons I suppose at the moment still. /sad and sick 23 year Apple veteran.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. I don't know how to do that. Sorry. PS: I can confirm they don't really mind about feature suggestion since I proposed to add seconds to the status bar on iPhone and iPad about 2-3 years ago but they still haven't done anything about that. But I can understand they receive a lot of things both to improve or to add as well as bug reports. So I think feature request isn't the most important thing to them.

Comment: The problem is their developer feedback team is crap now. They used to be very responsive when we'd give them bug reports, but now whether it is a feature request or a bug report they don't seem to even reply - even when doing serious and significant testing on dot betas or release candidates. Apple quality is just not even close to what it was. I've heard stories from internal engineers being very depressed about how they are largely aimless in their core OS work now since everything is aimed at competing in the mobile marked for investor bottom line vs user experience.

Comment: I have also seen comments or answers here (on AD) saying that the OP should file a bug report or suggest a feature or give their feedback (at apple.com/feedback) but they also mentioned that they should not expect to have an answer and that the product development team will read the message but won't reply. This appears to be taken as if it was a norm.

Comment: I go a more direct route &, with my developer account, file reports. Like I said, in the past they really were great, but starting maybe around several years ago it seems like they did something drastic that created effectively a dysfunctional system. I suspect they outsourced their division somewhere & have poor training / low expectations in some respect now in that area... which is confusing, but the case. One thing that has been highly painful is their lack of multi-selection of text after the major iWork "upgrade". It's not much better on the UX than MS Office now compared to how it was.